# Error querying SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table

```
create table #t(id int, amt int)

insert into #t values(1, 40), (1, 20), (1, 10), (2, 100), (2, 120), (2, 400)
```

I need output like this!

```
id  amt
1    70
1    70
1    70
2    620
2    620
2    620
```

I tried

```
SELECT
    id, SUM(amt) 
FROM
    #t 
GROUP BY
    id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This !

```
select id,sum(amt) over(partition by id) as amt from #t
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select  id
,       sum(amt) over (partition by id)
from    #t
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ffd3/1/0)

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I think [SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and later

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id, c.amt from #t as a
left outer join 
(SELECT b.id, SUM(b.amt) as amt FROM   #t as b  GROUP BY  id ) as c on c.id=a.id
```